# Is there a function to concatenate a queue of strings in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

Generally, one could do this:

```
string a;
a = {a, " first"};
a = {a, " second"};
a = {a, " third"};
```

From what I understand, this means that `a` is continuously reallocated for the concatenated string each time. Is there a magical `join` function that'll work like so that may be more performant?

```
string a;
string a_q[$];
a_q = '{"first", "second", "third"};
a = a_q.join(); // a = {a_q} doesn't work as {a_q} returns another queue;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a bit-stream cast: (LRM section 6.24.3 Bit-stream casting)

```
a = string'(a_q);
```

Comment: I figured you'd be the one to reply, thanks! I remember the guy from Amiq saying this could be done during DVCon '19 and I was curious how.

Comment: EDA playground example for people to refer to: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3diQ

Comment: Please move the static variable declaration outside the always block